# Dictionary Program using Arraylist and Text File

Tags: java, string, dictionary, arraylist, compare

Currently I am writing a program, for learning purposes, that is more or less a user defined dictionary. You are given a word, and then you input the corresponding word in English, and then it should tell you whether or not it is true or false, depending on what was put in as a answer previously.

Now, the trouble I am having is that I am currently unable to figure out how to check if the user input is correct, as I do not know how to compare the 2 values within the arraylist.

Currently I have this:

```
public void add(String question, String answer) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    wordlist.add(new WordPair(question, answer));
}
```

to add new elements to the array, which is just 2 strings, and then I am stuck on this:

```
public boolean checkGuess(String question, String quess)
{

}
```

which is where I want to compare the 2 strings. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Loop through the list, check if question equals the question of current pair && guess equals the answer of current pair, return true, else return false. If no such question was found, return false. A Map, however might be more convenient.

Comment: Ye, I was told that a map could be more useful, but this is mostly a exercise in using arraylists, together with writing to files. Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `equals` method in your Word class and simply do :

```
public boolean checkGuess(String question, String quess)
{
    return wordlist.contains(new WordPair(question, quess));
}
```

I assumed that each question is unique.
Note that a `Map` would be a better implementation.

Comment: Okay, so I kind of understand what is that you do with this method, but can you quickly explain how this checks the answer?
It goes through and just checks if the arraylist contains Question,and then checks if there is a value next to it?

Comment: This will check if such a WordPair question already exists in your arrayList. If it exists, it means that the guess is valid. You can check this here (note that equals it not properly overriden) : http://ideone.com/l3vruU . Note that a Map would be a better implementation. Additionally, I assumed that each question is unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

if I then do this: http://ideone.com/FGgigC it will check it, and then give me the system outputs depending on whether or not the word pair is there, correct?

Comment: @MadsRosenmeyer You can do this, but the method should be void instead of boolean because you're returning true each time (that means that every guess is correct)

Comment: I also saw that @Richie Hugh showed me a method called equalsIgnoreCase(), is there a way to implement this? Because this would allow the user to input the word in whatever shape they want without having to worry about case, or does this method ignore case?

Comment: Instead of calling equals on the string attribute (like I did) you can use equalsIgnoreCase(). Yes this method ignore case. I.e "Hello".equalsIgnoreCase("hElLo") returns true.

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it all working now with a few adjustments here and there! :D

Answer (score 0):

To compare two strings you would use the equals() method:

```
String a = "a";
String b = "a";
if(a.equals(b)){
    //TRUE
}
```

To cycle through the array list you can use a for each loop

```
for(WordPair pair : wordlist){
    if(guess.equals(pair.getAnswer())){
    // Equals the word
    }
}
```

alternatively `equalsIgnoreCase()` can be used if the capitalisation of the word is not considered important.

```
String a = "A";
String b = "a";
if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)){
// TRUE
}
```

Comment: There is no method called getAnswer in my java. Not sure if that has something to do with version, or what? 
Thanks for your help though! :)

Comment: Ah sorry, you should have get and set methods in your WordPair class which will allow you to get the values contained in the Object, like: 
`public String getAnswer(){
return answer;
}`